# Hyperref package crashes

Tags: hyperref, babel

I m kinda new to latex and i m working on a project for algebra. After a while I learnt about `hyperref` which would help with the `\autoref` instead of having to label every time. However whenever i try to include the package, for some reason it crashes in the compile. The preamble is this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πρόταση}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Ορισμός}[chapter]

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][\en Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};%
}
\newcommand\Connect[3][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[<->,red,>=latex,#1] (#2.north east) -- ( $ (#3.north west) + (-20pt,0) $ );%
}
\author{Χναράς Φοίβος\\ \large επιβλέπουσα: κ.Χαραλάμπους}
\title{Εισαγωγή στην Αλγεβρική Γεωμετρία \\ \large Ειδικό Θέμα}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Αφφινικά Αλγεβρικά σύνολα και Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr  }
\section{Τοπολογία \en Zariski \gr }
blah blah... 
     \begin{paracol}{3}

        \subsection*{$k^n=k\times k \times ... \times k$}
            \switchcolumn \subsection*{}
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$k[X_1,...,X_n]$} 
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$\bigcup$} 
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{}
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$\bigcup$} 
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$V(S)$} 
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$\rightleftarrows$}
        \switchcolumn \subsection*{$S$} 
         \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, it fails and it pops the message

```
Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }

Paragraph ended before \bbl@tempd was complete. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }

Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }

Use of \HyPsd@RemoveMask doesn't match its definition. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }

Undefined control sequence. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }



Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }

Argument of \HyPsd@CheckCatcodes has an extra }. ...� Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr }
```

and so on. The first chapter is introduction and is not enumerated. The first problem pops up on the first chapter (which is enumerated).

Needless to say without the `hyperref` it has no problem compiling. If anyone could help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: You are not showing enough code. Delete the .toc file, recompile and if the problem persists show a complete example ending with \end{document} (try to keep it short. Even if you don't know what is important, you can remove some lines and test if they mattered).

Comment: Add option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto` to the options for `hyperref` to get support for Unicode bookmarks. If the error is not yet fixed, add the relevant code that causes the error and remove unnecessary packages and definitions.

Comment: doesn't change anything with either unicode or pdfencoding=auto. The problem seems to be with the chapter/ sections/subsections etc but i can't figure what s gone wrong exactly

Comment: What are your definitions of `\en` and `\gr`?  Without these the code compiles without complaint.

Comment: the project is in greek so they are new commands to swap between english and greek. i did not include the new commands in here to not take up any more space.

Comment: Off topic: In the argument of the `\chapter` directive, should it be `Αλγεβρικά` instead of `Αγλεβρικά`? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace lines 46 and 47 with:

```
\chapter{Αφφινικά Αλγεβρικά σύνολα και Αγλεβρικά  \textlatin{varieties}  }
\section{Τοπολογία \textlatin{Zariski} }
```

Instead of using `\en` and `\gr` it is safer to use `\textlatin{}` just whenever you want to write in english.

Answer (score 2):

The macros from the first version

```
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
```

are missing in [revision 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/407919/4).
They are used in a chapter title:

```
\chapter{Αφφινικά Αλγεβρικά σύνολα και Αγλεβρικά \en varieties \gr  }
```

`\selectlanguage` should not be used this way, because it changes the document language, not just the language for one word. Package `babel` provides `\foreignlanguage`:

```
\chapter{Αφφινικά Αλγεβρικά σύνολα και Αγλεβρικά \foreignlanguage{english}{varieties}}
```

To get rid of the errors caused by `\selectlanguage` in `\en` and `\gr` in bookmark strings:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\en\relax
  \let\gr\relax
}
```

Also, the following options are recommended (support for UTF-8 characters and better support for math symbols in bookmarks):

```
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
```